# How to take a screenshot of contents of an Activity, including PopupWindows and AlertDialogs?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am trying to get a Bitmap of everything that is displayed on the screen of an application. I am currently retrieving the view and its screenshot with the following:

```
View viewToCapture = activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
... // some code here for enabling drawing cache if necessary, etc
Bitmap screenshot = viewToCapture.getDrawingCache();
```

The resulting screenshot displays what I want, unless a `PopupWindow` or `AlertDialog` is currently open. They seem to not have been within the view hierarchy under the root view. Is there an alternative view that I can use in order to capture everything that is on the screen? I am not interested in capturing anything that is outside of the application, such as the notification bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a bitmap of the activity window, and a bitmap of the dialog window, then using a canvas to layer the images over eachother.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;

public static Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
    try {
         Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,  bmp1.getConfig());
         Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
         canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, 0, 0, null);
         canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 0, 0, null);
         return bmOverlay;

 } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace() }
```

Comment: Would it be possible for me to get access to any PopupWindows and AlertDialogs in an activity without having created them? I am making a library that takes the screenshot, so I do not know whether a PopupWindow or AlertDialog would be present.

Comment: make the user pass in the instance of the popupwindow or alertdialog, then call whichever.isShowing() and handle it from there on

Comment: I was afraid that this would be the only solution. Would like to make it as easy as possible to use. Thanks for the info! Can you add this to your answer? I will then accept it.

Comment: is there a way for me to get the view of a Dialog while having only a reference to it?

Comment: You can't use the same method as the one you mentioned in your question? `dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView()`

Comment: The description of `getWindow()` on the dev site weirded me out a bit. Wasn't sure that this was the correct way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to capture everything you would have to use the ddms tool to take a screen shot then crop out anything you didn't want like the notification bar.

Comment: I am aware that I can do so, but I would like to process the screenshot programmatically in my app.